# Do pointers also point to C style strings?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-pointer

From my knowledge of pointers if, am right, pointers are holder of memory address, so how does pass by const char pointer which took in an RVALUE even work.

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Log("hello");
}
```

From what remember from pass by address in my pointers lessons, the argument entered will be stored in the `const char* message` argument as a memory address to whatever variable but here's the case where `"hello"` is a rvalue with no identity so how does this work.

Comment: Handy reading: [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Quoting: *Evaluating a string literal results in a string literal object with [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Whether all string literals are stored in [nonoverlapping objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Subobjects) and whether successive evaluations of a string literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.* It's the address of the *string literal object* that the pointer gets.

Comment: "hello" is a string literal here. That's ok. It has a place in memory, with an address.

Comment: C++ may complain about ptrs to rvalues though. See my Q here: [gcc c++ how to disable the `-Wno-error=permissive` error when `-fpermissive` and `-Werror` are both on? (Passing ptrs to R-values in C vs C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71270747/4561887)

Comment: @GabrielStaples so can i access their memory through the & just like other variables

Comment: String constants like this point to immutable data (read-only), but are otherwise regular pointers.

Comment: String literals are lvaules not rvalues.   This piece of information kind of breaks the premise of the question.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category  _"...The following expressions are lvalue expressions: ... a string literal... "_

Comment: Ammishaddai Boakye, yes. Try it out to be sure. But, apparently string literals are lvalues, as @RichardCritten pointed out. Note that cppreference.com is a community wiki though (I help edit it even), not an official source. I trust it though, same as Wikipedia.

Comment: C++ Draft Standard [\[expr.prim.literal\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.literal) _"...A string-literal is an lvalue designating a corresponding string literal object..."_

Comment: @tadman "*String constants ... are otherwise regular pointers*" - more accurately, string literals are `const char[]` arrays, which *decay* into pointers to the 1st char in certain context, like when passed as a function parameter.